# Javascript find and replace style attribute in HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I have a requirement to search through an HTML field and replace any instance of `<img style>` with `<img style = display: block>`.

I have this working for the first instance of this occurence in the field. However, sine this only works for the first occurence I need to be able loop through them to replace each one.

How should I construct a loop to complete this task?

Note: I am using ServiceNow so I need this to use regular JavaScript without libraries (such as jQuery).
The starting code is below:

```
var note = current.work_notes; // Get contents of the HTML field in ServiceNow similar to getElementByID
var noteStyle = note.replace("\<img style\=\"", "\<img style\=\"display\: block\; ");
```

Comment: Why are you placing all of the extra escape characters ( \ ) there? You don't need them except for when you're escaping a `"`

Comment: You should really be doing this with the DOM rather than text.  It will make things a lot easier on you.

Comment: I'm using ServiceNow and the best practice is to not use DOM since the global structure is often modified in system updates.

Comment: Any reason why people are voting this question down?

Comment: Something like this could probably to the job if you specify the parent node (in this case I wrote document): `var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img'); for(var i=0; i<imgs.length; i++){imgs[i].style.display = "block";}` [**See here**](http://jsfiddle.net/d893oyqv/). If you don't want to change your code, [Kenneth's answer should be your #1 solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31460857/1451422)

Comment: Thanks guys Kenneth's solution has worked for my purposes. You are very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be performing a local replace instead of a global replacement. What that means is you find the first instance from the source string you provide, whereas a global `replace` will yield all instances in the source string to be changed.

To do this, you will need to change the code to be something like below, so that it includes the necessary command to globally `replace` that string:

```
var note = current.work_notes; // Get contents of the HTML field in ServiceNow similar to getElementByID
var noteStyle = note.replace(/\<img style\=\"/g, "\<img style\=\"display\: block\; ");
```